# How to have a sliding animation from the bottom to the top with CSS?

Tags: css

I've spent the past hour trying to find a way to get a sliding animation from bottom to top using only CSS. It's supposed to be a test tube with fluid filling it. ([This is what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc3R2.png)), however during the animation it overflows around the edges at the bottom and doesn't sit flush ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkExC.png)).

HTML & CSS:

```css
.testTube #border {
  width: 40px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 25px 25px;
  position: absolute;
}

.testTube #fluidLeft {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  background-color: #ff007f;
  border-radius: 0% 0% 0% 25px;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: fluid;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.testTube #fluidRight {
  width: 20px;
  height: 0px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  background-color: #ff1a8c;
  border-radius: 0% 0% 25px 0%;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: fluid;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fluid {
  from {
    height: 0px;
    margin-top: 167px;
  }
  to {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 67px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="testTube">
  <div id="border"></div>
  <div id="fluidLeft"></div>
  <div id="fluidRight"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the #fluidLeft and #fluidRight divs into the #border div. That way, you can add "overflow: hidden" on to the border div (now the parent) which will make it so the fluid divs (now children of the border div) don't overlap outside of the border. I also tweaked the "margin-left" on the fluids by 2px so it was centered in the tube.

```css
.testTube #border {
  width: 40px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 25px 25px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.testTube #fluidLeft {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff007f;
  border-radius: 0% 0% 0% 25px;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: fluid;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.testTube #fluidRight {
  width: 20px;
  height: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #ff1a8c;
  border-radius: 0% 0% 25px 0%;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: fluid;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fluid {
  from {
    height: 0px;
    margin-top: 167px;
  }
  to {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 67px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="testTube">
  <div id="border">
    <div id="fluidLeft"></div>
    <div id="fluidRight"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help @Steven! If all is well, you can mark this response as an answer so other users know the question is resolved (= Have a great day and happy coding!